# "Well Solved Solutions" For Nonstandard Questions

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to ask questions based on "well solved" problems? What if the question has certain limitations that prevent the standard use of a "well-solved" problem? For example if the user cannot use a standard library or another accepted library (i.e `boost`), is it still an acceptable question? Should we discourage these types of questions being asked?

User comment:

> There is no point to the question (because it is a well know SOLVED
>   problem). Asking it is silly. There is a difference between not being
>   able to use the standard library and copying code (which just happens
>   to come from the standard library presumably you can still get a copy
>   to look at).

Example question: [Sine function in C / C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5211/7394)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that as long as the question has some limitation on it that it is an acceptable question. I recommend use of the [nonstandard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonstandard) tag to indicate that the "well solved solution" is not applicable for the question.

Standard libraries are simply that, standard and for general use. We shouldn't discourage questions that have specific constraints and don't follow standard use. I don't think Code Review should become a simple homework or detailed question site.

Plus, I feel an answer asserting to simply look up the source code of a standard library should not be considered a "good" answer. This is very little teaching value in that response.

Comment: I disagree with your first point about using a "nonstandard" meta tag, there *some* valid reasons for creating your own weel (eg. specific un-met requirements, education) this information would be better placed in the question rather than using a tag. I agree with your third point, there are licence/copyright issues with simply copying code like that, we defiantly should should not be encouraging it. I'm not really sure what your second point is.

Comment: @BrianReichle, the second point ties into the third point a little. Pretty much we shouldn't discourage any type of question.

Comment: I wouldn't go quite that far, the "question" should still be some sort of request for a code review and should contain any information necessary for the review. But yes, we should accept review requests for code in any programming/scripting language ([config files are still off-topic though](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180/is-this-really-code)) be it for homework, self education or production code.